# jquery events not firing on ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using Jquery 1.7.2

On initial page load I am executing the following script in an external JS loaded at the end of the page and wrapped in $(document).ready(function(){

```
    $('.accordionContent,.accordionContent-settings').hide();
$('.accordion-comments').click(function(){
            var target=$(this).attr('href');
            if($(target).css('display')=='none')
            {
                $(target).show();
                $(this).text('Hide Comments');
            }
            else
            {
                $(target).hide();
                $(this).text('Comments');
            }
            return false;
            });
```

The code essentially hides the form contained in this unordered list and reveals the form when the "Comments" link is clicked. The wording is then changed to Hide Comment and when clicked again the form is hidden again.

```
<ul class="sportswire-posts quarterfont">
                        <li>                            
                            <p><a href="/modals.cfm?action=profile_glimpse&script=%2Findex%2Ecfm%2Fgroup%2F3450%2Faction%2Fdashboard&member_id=5" rel="facebox" class="capitalize">Todd John</a> joined the team &quot;<a href="http://shootingattackclinic.playerspace.com/local_sports_teams.cfm?group=628">Mercury</a>&quot;.</p>
                            <p class="comments-date">11:38 AM EST on January 31, 2013</p>
                        </li>                       


                            <li class="comments-link">
                                <a href="#comments35800" class="accordion-comments">Comments</a> 
                            </li>                       

                        <li class="accordionContent posts-comments" id="comments35800">

                                <form method="post" action="/index.cfm/group/3450/action/dashboard/m0dal_update/leave_feedback/member_id/68/comment_type/17/id/35800">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="expandingArea">
                                                <pre><span></span><br /></pre>
                                                <textarea name="str_comment" message="Enter a comment." rows="4" cols="10" required="Yes" html="No" id="str_comment24234"></textarea>                                           
                                            </div>                                      
                                            <div class="pixelspacer10"></div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <input name="Post Comment" type="submit" value="Post Comment" />
                                        </li>                               
                                    </ul>
                                </form>

                        </li>                                                                               
                    </ul>
```

The problem is when I make an ajax call to get additional ULS like the the one above (with different ids of course).

```
$(document).on("click",'.siteusemore',function()
        {
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        var myscript = window.siteusemore_script || null;       
        if(ID)
            {
                $("#siteusemore"+ID).html('<img src="/images/processing.gif" />');                  
                $.ajax({type: "POST",url: myscript,data: "lastmsg="+ ID, cache: false,
                    success: function(html){                                    
                        $("ol#siteuseupdates").append(html);                
                        $('.accordionContent').hide();                      
                        $('.accordion-comments').on("click",function(){
                        var target=$(this).attr('href');
                        if($(target).css('display')=='none')
                        {
                            $(target).show();
                            $(this).text('Hide Comments');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $(target).hide();
                            $(this).text('Comments');
                        }
                        });                                                                                     
                        $("#siteusemore"+ID).remove();                      
                    }
                });             
            }
        else
        {
            $(".siteusemorebox").html('The End');                       
        }               
        return false;
    });
```

The above method works inconsistently. The hide/show event fires for some items, but not all. I can't seem to figure out why I just can't get it to work for every comment/form combination loaded via ajx. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was assigning event handler using the click() function. This will only bind the event to elements that exist when the page first loads. You need to change that to use on() instead:

```
$("body").on("click", ".accordion-comments", function(){
     //put he click code in here
});
```

I was binding click event twice - once when the page first loads, and then again after your ajax call. Using the on() function means you only need to bind it when the page first loads, so remove it from the success function of the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Jeffrey,

The first problem I see is in here:

```
var target=$(this).attr('href');
if($(target).css('display')=='none')
{..}
```

Your problem is the following, after:

```
var target=$(this).attr('href');
```

the variable "target" will be holding a string. On the next line:

```
if($(target).css('display')=='none')
```

You are trying to use the string as a jQuery object, and that is going to lead to errors.

I haven't tried this, but I would recommend:

```
$('.accordion-comments').on("click",function(){
    if($(this).find("a").is(":visible"))
    {
        $(this).find("a").show();
        $(this).text('Hide Comments');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).find("a").hide();
        $(this).text('Comments');
    }
});
```

The main changes are that you are referring to the object correctly, and the use of the "is" (jquery utility).

I hope this helps,

-Ricardo

Comment: The above works in revealing the hidden div but does not conceal it when the link is clicked again.

Comment: Just did a minor change. Instead of hiding the entire div, with the latest edit, you will hide/show the anchor side inside the target.

Comment: Now I have:  $('.sportswire-posts').on('click', '.accordion-comments', function(){
 var target=$(this).attr('href'); 
 if($(this).find("a").is(":visible"))
 {
  $(target).find("a").show();
  $(this).text('Hide Comments');
 }
 else
 {
        $(target).find("a").hide();
        $(this).text('Comments');
 }
 return false;
 });

and both hide and show are unresponsive on click.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had left the "target" variable there. You should not have it anywhere as it is no longer used. The main thing is for you to understand the cause of your problem... In this case it could be the use of target as an object. I would use the developer tools to debug the JS.

Comment: I copie pasted the code exactly as its written above. onclick triggers no response.

Comment: Jeffrey, please be aware that I am not testing these (busy). I am merely giving you pointers. You changed how you call the click event, so you have to test and see what you are getting with $(this).

Comment: Oh I understand completely, really I do. I don't expect anything and appreciate your contributions.

Comment: If you have the time and the inclination to assist, I'd be happy to take this offline and discuss it over email?

Comment: Jeffery, I've created a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/EtcjD/ - The issue here is that you are using the same UL for comments, link to show/hideand forms. In the future I would recommend having them separate. Keep the comments on one list, and the rest separate. In the solution provided I simple added a class to the actual comments so you can target them via jquery.

Comment: Ricardo, your solution here hides the status update and not the comments on them, as the intention. I think it may be better for you to see the actual page itself:
http://shootingattackclinic.playerspace.com/index.cfm/group/3450/action/login

username: seolms 
password: test

The recent activity feed is the one Im having issues with.